# Casting From A List To A Collection

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, casting

I have a class TreeNode:

```
public abstract class TreeNode<T>{
   .
   .
   .

    public Collection<TreeNode<T>> children;

    public void clear(){
       if(children == null) 
      return;

       Iterator<TreeNode<T>> iterator = children.iterator();
       while(iterator.hasNext()){
          TreeNode<T> node = iterator.next();
          node.clear();
       }

       children.clear();
   }
   .
   .
   .

}
```

I then have a class ListTreeNode:

```
public class ListTreeNode<T> extends TreeNode<T>{
   .
   .
   .

   public ListTreeNode(T data, List<ListTreeNode<T>> children){
      this.data = data;
      this.root = null;
      this.children = children;
      this.childIndex = 0;
   }

   .
   .
   .

}
```

I get a compiler error saying that I cannot convert from `List<ListTreeNode<T>>` to `Collection<TreeNode<T>>`. Shouldn't I be able to, since `List` is a subinterface of `Collection` and `ListTreeNode` is a subclass of `TreeNode`? Also, I have a corresponding class `SetTreeNode` which uses `Set` instead of `List` and there are no errors in its corresponding constructor where I have `this.children = children;` .

Comment: I don't really see why you have to pass a List<ListTreeNode<T>> and not List<TreeNode<T>>, is this really intentional? That said, since ListTreeNode extends TreeNode, List<ListTreeNode<T>> is not assignable to Collection<TreeNode<T>> but rather Collection<? extends TreeNode<T>>

Comment: @DylanSmith: Except that one deals with C#, and this question deals with Java.  (Although the answers are similar, they're not identical.)    The first duplicate I could find is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit), but I'm sure there are many more.

Comment: ugh, didn't notice the Java...nevermind

Comment: I intentionally passed in a List<ListTreeNode<T>> so that you cannot pass in any other class that derives from TreeNode. I originally changed children to Collection<?> but I got some warnings from that. So I changed it to Collection<? extends TreeNode<T>> and that got rid of the warnings. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with casting a `List<T>` to a `Collection<T>`, and everything to do with casting a `List<SomeDerivedClass>` to a `List<SomeBaseClass>`.  Java generics are **invariant**, and the behavior you are looking for is **covariance**.

This question has been raised many times on StackOverflow before.  Here is one example: [Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit)

Comment: Thanks. I tried searching for it but that one must have gotten by me.

Answer (score 2):

A `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>`. If it were, you could be able to do this:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> listOfObjects = listOfStrings;
listOfObjects.add(new Integer(3));
```

As you see, this would ruin the type-safety of generic collections.

You should probably use a `Collection<? extends TreeNode<T>>`